# Firebase .on() listener causes Cordova iOS app crash

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have made a blank, brand new Cordova app (-v 6.3.1), and built for iOS. The app does nothing except the following:

```
var ref = new Firebase('url-to-firebase-leaf-node-with-4000-children');
ref.on("child_added", function(child, prev) {
    console.log("here");
});
```

Deploy to iPhone. The app crashes, and Xcode cites the following:

`WebThread (7): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xbbadbeef)` inside of `bmalloc::VMHeap::grow()` .

If I do this rather:

`var ref = new Firebase('url-to-firebase-leaf-node-with-100-children');` then the app doesn't crash.

This is clearly a memory problem, but how can it be resolved? With 1.5Mb of data being pulled down from 4,000 child nodes, I wouldn't have imagined this should be using up all available memory. Please avoid suggestions of not pulling all the data - the app needs all the data and works fine on Android.

Comment: I should also note that I am using Firebase 2.4.2.

Comment: Also to note is that the total size of data being retrieved from Firebase is 1.5Mb.

Comment: Update: I have tried using WKWebView as well, but this too crashes.

Answer (score 2):

The native crash is pretty expressive. The application runs out of memory.

The Firebase SDK builds an in-memory mirror of the database using your subscriptions. Even if your `child_added` callback does not do anything with the child snapshots, this internal tree uses memory for *all the data* under the node.

Therefore you should consider using limits on your subscription, introducing pagination, or even restructuring the database if it fits your domain model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @vzsg. The problem is that my app needs all 4000 child nodes, and this works fine on Android. I have tried to do a paginated initial pull of the data, using promises of 50 child nodes each and using `.once('value')` for each page of 50 nodes. This actually works for getting the data once, but I need to listen for changes thereafter. So if I try add the `.on` afterwards, it crashes again.

Comment: Or is there not a way to allow the app to use more memory? I've tested this on a iPhone 6s and it crashes, but that device has more memory than some of the Android devices I've tested on which work fine.

Comment: Furthermore, is the memory exception a result of the _number_ of child nodes, or the _total amount of data_ stored in the child nodes? i.e. Would having a single child node with 2mb of data crash just the same as 4,000 child nodes containing a total of 2mb of data?

Comment: There is an overhead per child node, but I think the total data matters more. (This is just an opinion, as I don't have insights of the internals either.) Perhaps you could try to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView, if you haven't already switched?

Comment: Seems WKWebView would be a better option, but there don't seem to be any viable options. CrossWalk is not for iOS, the Telerik WKWebView plugin only works on old Cordova, and the Apache WKWebView Engine plugin doesn't seem to allow me to connect to Firebase. Do you know how I might be able to implement WKWebView?

Comment: I don't know. Personally I think you should reconsider that "your app needs to download everything". But this is getting too long for the comments.

Comment: It works on Android (tested up to 40,000 children) - that alone should be enough to justify it working on iOS IMO.

Comment: I think you should file a support ticket then.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the `child_added` listener, ensure that you have cached all of the data (through the aforementioned pagination technique, or otherwise).