# Firebase .on(value) on a large node causes iPhone browser to crash

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase-realtime-database

I made a simple HTML web page that connects to a Firebase database node. All it does is this:  `.on("value", function(snap) { alert(); })` .

The Firebase node contains about 4,000 child nodes, total of 1.5Mb of data.

I have tested opening this same webpage on the following device / configs:

1. Chrome on PC (WORKS)
2. Safari on MacBook (WORKS)
3. Chrome on Android device (WORKS)
4. Safari on iPhone (CRASHES)
5. Chrome on iPhone (CRASHES)

I've created an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/x8muxzqL/

If you navigate to that in a computer browser and run it, you should see an alert after a few seconds. If you try navigate to that in an iPhone browser and run, the browser will crash.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Given that it only happens on certain (mobile) devices, it is most likely related to memory usage. But it's hard to say anything more specific without seeing the [minimal code that reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you put a working reproduction of the problem into a jsbin/jsfiddle too, that is even more helpful.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen - I've added a jsFiddle in my question now.

Comment: It looks like Safari simply cannot handle the amount of data you load. If I change the jsfiddle to load the data one level lower in the tree, it works fine.

Comment: Sadly this what I suspected as well. I don't understand what happens when loading 1.5Mb of data from Firebase, but it seems to use a lot of memory in the process.

Comment: 1.5MB of JSON is quite a lot of data. When dealing with mobile devices: if you're not showing it on the screen, don't download it. You're probably going to show an aggregate of that data (e.g. a count of records) on the screen first. If a count is what you show, store the count in your database and load that. Loading a single count is going to eat up a lot less bandwidth (and memory) than loading 4000 records

Comment: Totally agree about only downloading what you need. The problem is I need instant offline lookup on that data in this app, so may have to find an alternate solution, or try restructure the Firebase data.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of what you have in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997522/firebase-on-listener-causes-cordova-ios-app-crash -- I think chunking the request or restructuring firebase are your best options